# Get total number of articles from a MediaWiki wiki programmatically

Tags: count, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

How can I get the total number of articles using the **MediaWiki API**?

I couldn't find it in the docs:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#Search_engine_features

Even a rough approximation is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=statistics and read the property `articles` of the `statistics` tag.

Comment: what's the difference between pages and articles? I thought it was basically the same thing!

Comment: pages also counts things like user pages and project pages, while articles only counts pages in the article (i.e. main) namespace.

Comment: Also, very short articles tend to be counted as pages. (I think the exact rule is that it must be in main namespace, contain an internal link and not be a redirect to be counted as an articel.)

Comment: To clear the somewhat implied separation, **articles is a subset of pages**. Any article is also a page, but many kinds of pages (as celtschk pointed out) are not considered articles.